# How to compare DateTimes when ActiveRecord returns time w/ timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

How do I solve this date and timzeone comparison problem in RSpec:

Code:

```
promotion.start_date.should == DateTime.strptime("2012-02-08", "%F")
```

Result:

```
Failure/Error: promotion.start_date.should == DateTime.strptime("2012-02-08", "%F")
  expected: Wed, 08 Feb 2012 00:00:00 +0000
       got: Wed, 08 Feb 2012 00:00:00 EST -05:00 (using ==)
  Diff:
  @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
  -Wed, 08 Feb 2012 00:00:00 +0000
  +Wed, 08 Feb 2012 00:00:00 EST -05:00
```

Comment: The only way I could get this working is if I did `promotion.start_date.to_i.should == Time.zone.parse("2012-02-08").to_i`  Unfortunately, if they don't match, it shows the expected and got time as an integers instead of readable dates now, which kind of stinks.  .to_i is needed for when dates don't begin at 00:00:00.  Are there any better ways?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have EST time zone on your development machine and UTC (default) in you Rails app. I would say that the error in your test is a legitimate one :) Set the same time zone in your Rails app `config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` and the error will go away.